# Plotting multiple Gini Coefficients on the same graph

Tags: python, pandas, gini

I am trying to plot the gini coefficient on a graph, showing different data for different variables (GDP_PPP and GDP_MER) to show the inequalities between gdp market exchange rate and gdp as gross national income. I am struggling to get both variables to appear on the same graph.

The below code is what I have done to calculate the Gini coefficient function:

```py
def GiniCoeff_plot(pop, resource):

    iuse = (np.logical_not(pop.isnull()) & np.logical_not(resource.isnull())) & np.greater(np.float64(resource),0)

    pop = pop[iuse]; pop = np.array(np.float64(pop)) 
    resource = resource[iuse]; resource = np.array(np.float64(resource)) 
    resource = resource/pop 
    resource2 = resource2[iuse]; resource = np.array(np.float64(resource2)) 
    resource2 = resource2/pop 
    
    pw = np.array([pop.tolist(), resource.tolist(), resource2.tolist()]); pw = pw.T 
    pw = pw[pw[:,1].argsort()]; (r, c) = pw.shape 

    pw2 = pw2[pw2[:,1].argsort()]; (r, c) = pw2.shape 

    fy = pw[:,0]/sum(pw[:,0]) 
    F = np.zeros(r+1); S = np.zeros(r+1); L = np.zeros(r+1) 
    F[1:r+1] = np.cumsum(fy) 
    S[1:r+1] = np.cumsum(fy*pw[:,1]) 
    S2[1:r+1] = np.cumsum(fy*pw[:,1]) 
    L = S/S[-1] 
    L2 = S2/S2[-1] 

    partarea1 = np.sum(fy.T * L[0:r])
    partarea2 = np.sum(fy.T * L[1:r+1])
    G = 1 - partarea1 - partarea2
    
    #ploting data
    plotflag=1
    if plotflag==1:
        plt.plot(F, L, '-b', label="observed")
        plt.plot(F, F, '--k', label="perfect eq.")
        plt.plot(F, L2, '-y', label='test')
        plt.xlabel("Population")
        plt.xticks(np.arange(0,1.1, step=0.1), ["{}%".format(i) for i in range(0,110,10)])
        plt.ylabel("Resources")
        plt.yticks(np.arange(0,1.1, step=0.1), ["{}%".format(i) for i in range(0,110,10)])
        plt.grid(color='k', linestyle='-', linewidth=0.1)
        plt.title("GINI: %.4f" %(G))
        plt.legend()
        plt.show() 
        
    return G
```

and:

```py
    pop =  pd.DataFrame(C04["pop"]); pop = pop[pop.applymap(isnumber)]; pop=pop["pop"] 
    resource =  pd.DataFrame(C04["gdp_mer"]); resource = resource[resource.applymap(isnumber)]; resource = resource["gdp_mer"]
    resource2 =  pd.DataFrame(C04["gdp_ppp"]); resource2 = resource2[resource2.applymap(isnumber)]; resource2= resource2["gdp_ppp"]
    
    G = GiniCoeff_plot(pop, resource, resource2)
    print("G = {:.4f}".format(G))
```

however I keep getting the error: `"TypeError: GiniCoeff_plot()` takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given"

Does anyone know how I can change it so that I can include the two variables? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: the error seems quite straight forward, you've passed 3 arguments to `GiniCoeff_plot`  : `pop, resource, resource2` where the function is expecting two

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm very mistaken, you've simply forgotten to add the argument to your function definition.

You currently have:

```
def GiniCoeff_plot(pop, resource):
```

But internally you refer to both `resource` and `resource2`.

I think all you need to do is to update the function declaration to accept the `resource2` as an argument instead of simply creating it internally:

```
def GiniCoeff_plot(pop, resource, resource2):
```